# Pip install ignores files in MANIFEST.in - how to structure the project correctly?

Tags: python, package, pip

I read a lot about this problem but could not find any solution, so I'll ask yet another question about it, since I'm not even sure if I use the correct folder structure for my Python package.

So basically I'm developing an application which uses the Tornado web-server framework and I want to package it, so the users can install it via `pip` and get access to a basic script to start the web server.

The directory structure is the following:

```
├── MANIFEST.in
├── README.md
├── config
│   └── default.cfg
├── docs
│   ├── Makefile
│   ├── _build
│   ├── _static
│   ├── _templates
│   ├── conf.py
│   ├── index.rst
├── foopackage
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── barmodule.py
│   └── bazmodule.py
├── setup.py
├── static
│   ├── css
│   │   ├── menu.css
│   │   └── main.css
│   ├── img
│   │   └── logo.png
│   ├── js
│   │   ├── ui.js
│   │   └── navigation.js
│   └── lib
│       ├── d3.v3.min.js
│       └── jquery-1.11.0.min.js
└── templates
    ├── index.html
    └── whatever.html
```

The Python code is as you can see in the package `foopackage`.

The `MANIFEST.in` file recursively includes the directories `config`, `static`, `templates`, and `docs`.

This is my `setup.py` (only the relevant parts:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(name='foo',
      version='0.1.0',
      packages=['foopackage'],
      include_package_data=True,
      install_requires=[
          'tornado>=3.2.2',
      ],
      entry_points={
          'console_scripts': [
              'foo=foopackage.barmodule:main',
          ],
      },
)
```

If I run `python setup.py sdist`, everything gets packaged nicely, the `docs`, `templates` and `config` files etc. are included. However, if I run `pip install ...`, only the `foopackage` gets installed and everything else is ignored.

How do I include those additional files to the install procedure? Is my directory structure  OK? I also read about "faking a package", so putting everything in a directory and touch a `__init__.py` file, but that seems pretty odd to me :-\

Comment: *PUSH* running into the same problem, did you find any solution?
I ended up using `package_data` in `setup.py` but i still hope there is a better solultion...

Comment: @ProfHase85 Sorry, forgot to add my solution. I added the answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem by moving the `static` directory to the actual Python module directory (`foopackage`). It seems that top level "non-package" folders are ignored otherwise.